# Unity - Models suddenly stuck in poses In-Editor and 3D Animations messed up across project

Tags: unity, animation, editors, rigging, bug

**Please Note: I'm having trouble placing pictures here, but I have a thread on the Unity Forums of this issue with images and additional video. Please refer: https://forum.unity.com/threads/models-suddenly-stuck-in-poses-in-editor-and-animations-messed-up-across-project.1334213/**

This has been torturing my team for the past month and a half and we're all very lost.

My team and I are using Unity 2020.3.27f1 LTS. We had setup many characters across the game. Of course, when we designed them and place them in the world in the Unity Editor, they are in their default T-Pose and animating once the game plays. This has been how the project's been for the past year.

Then about a month and a half ago I did a bunch of edits related to character animation and performances in a scene and pushed it. From there, all characters across the project broke in some way. I have no idea why as I only edited a few animations for select characters and their triggers. I didn't touch any code.

When I say they all broke, it's in various ways. Some characters stopped working entirely or partially; an example being a character with a long coat but now the coat itself no longer animated at all with the rest of the body. Some had parts of their rig that started to bend, distort, and move oddly in ways they never did before on animation, most prominently their hands in most cases. Some contorted into random positions for no reason...

However, the biggest problem is that almost every character model now holds a pose in the Unity editor. We have no idea why. It's like Unity saved their last posed position and has made it their default pose forever. They hold that pose no matter what. You can remove all their animation components and it will still hold that pose instead of a T-Pose. It could be a sitting position. It could be an idle pose. Sometimes it's in a cringing position that models go into when their rigs are broken... But almost all of them will animate properly on Play Mode... With some animation errors as mentioned above. And this is on EVERY character. You can see some examples in the images below.

We've been scrambling to figure out why such a problem has occurred and it has been a huge setback. There's no logical reason why such a project-wide problem just suddenly happened. I went back into the commit history to find where it started and it began with my commit... But I did nothing that should have caused something like this. I was tweaking animation performances in one scene which doesn't even feature most of the characters or anything related to them. Now it suddenly damns the whole project and every character has been affected even if I hadn't touched them in a long time.

The weird thing is that the animation errors at least have an odd fix mostly. For some, but not all of the characters, if I delete their rig in the prefab and then put a rig back in the prefab fresh from the project files, their animation issues are mostly solved... But there's nothing actually different about the rig at all. It makes zero sense. This does not fix the posing issue though.

So far, I have no clue what is happening or why. Even putting in the fresh rig does not save the character from becoming affected by the posing issue eventually. The only clue I've been able to find is that in Prefab Mode, it T-Poses as it should, but if I click the Show Overrides checkbox it goes back into that pose. This leads me to believe that there is an Override issue, but I couldn't have triggered anything like that project-wide, I never even knew Overrides like this were a thing until I looked into this clue.

This leads me to believe this is an editor problem because nothing me or any of my team could have done should have caused all this mess to happen. Now we have to redo weeks of work to try and fix some of these issues and we still don't know how to fully stop these problem or why it's happening. At least one of these characters are still even more distorted than the images below on animation and we don't know why. It has forced a crash when I was looking more deeply into the animations at one point. The project/unity seems much more unstable since this began. One of my teammates sent a version to Unity via the Report a Bug function, but whenever I tried doing so myself as well, it never worked. We have yet to hear anything.

Anyone have any idea what is going on?

Comment: If you think prefab overrides might have something to do with it, it could be worth inspecting the YAML text of either the prefab file, or it's instance in the scene YAML. Maybe some corrupt data got inserted somewhere. It would also help to explain what specific steps or changes you made when "fixing animation performance" — what specifically did you touch, which files were modified in that check-in and how? This can help us narrow down potential culprits.

Comment: Did you try doing a full asset reimport in case the cached files in the `Library` folder have gotten corrupted? Right-click anywhere in the Project panel and select "Reimport all"

Comment: @DMGregory I'm thinking that corruption might be the case, but I don't know how to really check in this instance and I don't know what is causing the override. This issue now happens on EVERY Scene to all Characters, even the ones I wasn't touching. It even happens in empty scenes where I import just the characters. When I said I was fixing the animation when I began notice this, I wasn't doing much. All I did was take 2 animations on one model modify their frame length by a frame or two because they were twitching a bit. Other than that, I mainly messed with 2 scenes and 2 anim controllers.

Comment: @Kevin Tried that already and unfortunately, it's no dice. Already tried reimporting and even deleting the entire project and downloading a fresh copy. Also deleted the Library. I even tried reinstalling Unity and using more recent versions still a problem.

Comment: Did you do a file diff of all the files touched by that check-in — even ones that you'd swear up and down you did not do anything to? Let's find what YAML actually changed, whether or not it had anything to do with the actions you took.

Comment: @DMGregory Yes, I did check this before and just checked again to make sure. There were only 2 characters altered in the changeset that I began noticing the issue: one edit is only for a character prefab, the other is the fbx of the male version of those background colored models (there are male, female, and child versions of them) where I chaged a few animations by a frame or two. Nothing that would have triggered anything like this from what I can tell.

Comment: I'm not asking you to repeat yourself. I'm asking you to share the file diff output from before and after the change. Whether or not it "would" have triggered the problem, you've determined that it DID (in that the problem does not appear if you revert back before this change). So now we need to get into the guts to investigate why.

Comment: @DMGregory Sorry, losing track of what I've explained since I'm asking in a lot of places. Actually correction about that. Now the problem does persist in previous changesets, even from like a year ago, when it certainly wasn't an issue before. No idea why. Not sure if this is what you mean, but here's a list of changes on one of the characters (the background crowd model. The only changes on it was the frames of 2 animations. This is from the same commit where I noticed the issue. Is this what you're asking about? https://imgur.com/a/QAN6XsN

Comment: If this commit is not sufficient to cause the issue (ie. it persists in previous versions — that's new information for us here), then its diff is probably not relevant. Next thing to check would be whether you've changed your Unity version or updated any packages in that time.